# Loading mysql table into python takes a very long time compared to R

Tags: python, mysql, r

I have a fairly large mysql table, about 30M rows, 6 columns, about 2gb when loaded into memory.

I work with both python and R.  In R, I can load the table into memory and it takes about 90 seconds.  But in python it takes 40 minutes.

I've tried it both with sqlalchemy and with plain pymysql.  The code is straightforward, for example, with sqlalchemy:

```
db_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:pass@host/database")
cnx = db_engine.connect()
table = pd.read_sql('select * from my_table',cnx)
cnx.close()
```

Without sqlalchemy:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**db_details)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from my_table')
table = pd.DataFrame(data=list(cursor),columns = cursor.column_names)
cnx.close()
```

Either way, it is much, much slower than R, which doesn't make much sense to me.  Why is this, and is there any way to speed it up?  Even a hack would do.

To add, pandas doesn't have anything to do with it taking so long.  In the second code snippet, if I just return `list(cursor)` instead of putting it  into a pandas DataFrame, it takes (basically) just as long.

On edit:
The DB is running on the same machine as R/Python, so everything should be identical in terms of throughput.

In R I am using DBI, and the R code I use is (basically) this:

```
require(DBI)
cnx <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MySQL"),dbname="database",username="user",password="pass",host="host")
table <- dbGetQuery(cnx,"select * from my_table")
```

********  RESOLVED (MOSTLY) ********

Thanks to helpful comments, particularly from @roganjosh, it appears that the issue is that the default mysql connector is written in python rather than C, which makes it very slow.  The solution is to use `MySQLdb`, which is a native C connector.

In my particular setup, running python 3 with anaconda, that wasn't possible because `MySQLdb` is only supported in python 2.  However, there is an implementation of `MySQLdb` for python 3 under the name `mysqlclient`.

Using this implementation the time is now down to about 5 minutes to read the whole table, not as fast as R, but much less than the 40 or so it was taking before.

Comment: I would isolate the conversion into a pandas dataframe but this is indeed interesting

Comment: Good point, I did that.  It's not the pandas conversion.  Simply getting the list of rows takes 40 minutes approx.

Comment: Is there network involved? Are you executing the script on the same machine as your database is on?

Comment: Actually what suprises me is the speed of R, not the speed of Python. I am also working with sqlite3 DB of that size and it does take long.

Comment: @alecxe Would that not be common between `R` and `Python` though?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis yes, I just want to make sure both R and Python are under the same external conditions here..could be things were executed from different hosts, for example.

Comment: Also it might be useful to post the `R`-code and add the `R`-tag as well. Let's get some insight from the R-guys too

Comment: Good points.  Yes, they are both running under the same external conditions (db on same machine as R/Python) and I added the R code.

Comment: I assume you've done some searching on this? I'm interested in the issue and there's actually quite a lot of people complaining about Python compared to other languages. Have you seen the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783735/python-5x-slower-than-perl-mysql-query)? Does it do anything?

Comment: I've done a little searching but didn't find that answer.  That seems to require MySqlDb which I'm now trying to install but not having any luck with anaconda and python 3.5.  But it makes sense that if the connector is written in python it would be slow.

Comment: Ugh, this might be an issue. I'm on Windows so if anything is tough to install I always go to the unofficial binaries so I was going to suggest doing that if you were on Windows too. But then I've just seen that he only [has 2.7](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python) .... and I've never known his collection to be out date. It might not exist for Python 3 :(. If that is the case, you might be able to use `rpy` to run the query but that is less than ideal.

Comment: Well, I found a thing called mysqlclient which claims to be an implementation of MySqlDb which works with Python 3.  We'll see.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Success!  Using `mysqlclient`, which can be installed from `conda`, the time for loading the table is down to about 5 minutes.  Still not R speed, but much better than before.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it as an answer.  I'm open to further improvements, but at this point it's not worth my time trying to get it down from 5 minutes to 90 seconds, since I don't do this query very often.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to helpful comments, particularly from @roganjosh, it appears that the issue is that the default mysql connector is written in python rather than C, which makes it very slow.  The solution is to use `MySQLdb`, which is a native C connector.

In my particular setup, running python 3 with anaconda, that wasn't possible because `MySQLdb` is only supported in python 2.  However, there is an implementation of `MySQLdb` for python 3 under the name `mysqlclient`.

Using this implementation the time is now down to about 5 minutes to read the whole table, not as fast as R, but much less than the 40 or so it was taking before.

I'm still open to suggestions that would make it faster, but my guess is that this is as good as it's going to get.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a pure C/C++ [`ultramysql` MySQL driver](https://github.com/esnme/ultramysql) which can be used with the [`umysqldb` adapter](https://github.com/hongqn/umysqldb). The projects are not active, but could be of use for a one-time thing - I would not be using them in production though.

Since `pymysql` is a pure-Python driver, you may also try running it on [`PyPy`](http://pypy.org/).